# Can I supress the output of certain rspec expectations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

By output I mean either the `.`,`F`or`*` for passing, failing or pending expectations. Could I make certain expectations not display nothing?

```
describe User do
    it "one"
    it "two"
    it "three"
end
```

This results in:

```
***

Pending:
  User one
    # Not yet implemented
    # ./spec/model/user_spec.rb:89
  User two
    # Not yet implemented
    # ./spec/model/user_spec.rb:90
  User three
    # Not yet implemented
    # ./spec/model/user_spec.rb:91

Finished in 0.00063 seconds
3 examples, 0 failures, 3 pending
```

Is it possible to do something along these lines:

```
describe User do
    it "one"
    it "two", no_display: true
    it "three"
end
```

So that I get this output (Note the `*` for expectation `two` isn't there):

```
**

Pending:
  User one
    # Not yet implemented
    # ./spec/model/user_spec.rb:89
  User two
    # Not yet implemented
    # ./spec/model/user_spec.rb:90
  User three
    # Not yet implemented
    # ./spec/model/user_spec.rb:91

Finished in 0.00063 seconds
3 examples, 0 failures, 3 pending
```

Maybe some sort of before method could do this? I'm just creating some custom output to help me with RoR model validations, and the **expectation** that displays validation errors (it needs access to the `subject` variable), is an expectation in itself so it leaves a  slightly confusing trailing dot on my console.

It's a small point, but if it could be suppressed I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can provide your own "custom formatter" and control this and any other aspect of the output. The mechanism for specifying your own formatter is described at https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-14/docs/formatters/custom-formatters and http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Formatters

Although I have not tested it, it appears that if you just want to silence the one-character result summaries, or make them dependent on an example attribute, you can just redefine the `example_passed`, `example_failed` and `example_pending` methods.

The code for the default `ProgressFormatter` is available at https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/b9293ae4e3ea19d0214ffa2f3ec4e87acc54debd/lib/rspec/core/formatters/progress_formatter.rb

Comment: OKay, I'm getting somewhere with this but I'm still not quite there. I s there a good tutorial around? Or at least, a github link to rspec's default formatter for some inspiration?

Comment: Check out the `BaseTextFormatter` link at the bottom of the page at the second link I gave you.

Comment: See updated answer for link to the default `ProgressFormatter`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry if this is a bit dense, but could you look at this? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7750665 . Where does "example: should be right" come from? And where does "Finished in 0.00651 seconds
1 example, 0 failures" come from? Now that I'm using my own formatter?

Comment: You only redefined one of the formatter methods, so you're inheriting the behavior for everything else (e.g. summary output at the end).

Comment: I noticed you didn't pass the initialization parameter to `super` - that may explain the `example: ...` text appearing.

Comment: So what caused the `example: ...` to go away?

Comment: Your point about how I'm inheriting all other behaviour. I can do this if I so wish https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7751120 . Why should I pass an initialization parameter to the super method? Could you elaborate on that possibly? Last question I promise :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42350/discussion-between-peter-alfvin-and-starkers)